# linking to a .dylib in vs code

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to link my .dylib file when compiling in my sandbox folder but getting an *unknown / unsupported file* warning from the compiler followed by Undefined symbol in my class. The library appears to be correct with just a wrapped printf and shows as:
`Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64`

Any help with building and linking this?  Thank you.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        { 

        { 
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++ --verbose  -m64 -dynamiclib -fPIC -o ${workspaceFolder:Engine}/bin/libfoo.dylib ${workspaceFolder:Engine}/src/test.cpp"
        },


            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [ 
                "--verbose",
                "${workspaceFolder:Sandbox}/src/testinglib.cpp",
                "${file}",
                "-I", 
                 "${workspaceFolder:Engine}/src",
                "-L", 
                "${workspaceFolder:Engine}/bin",
                 "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder:Sandbox}/bin/testinglib",      
                 ]
        }
    ]
}
```

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Development/Engine/.vscode/tasks.json, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-unsupported file format ( 0x7B 0x0A 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x2F 0x2F 0x20 0x53 0x65 0x65 0x20 0x68 0x74 0x74 )
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Engine::Print()", referenced from:
      _main in libtesting-77a284.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: `lib` is an unfortunate name for your dylib.  Try calling it `libfoo.dylib` and then use `-l foo` in your json file.  I think also that you might need the `L` stuff all on one line.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  When calling it `libfoo` it still complains about not finding `foo`, Also I noticed if I put`"L ${workspaceFolder:Engine}/bin"` it complains that directory cannot be found for -L.

Keeping the -L arguments on 2 lines without the -l seems to get a bit further.
now it tries to `link with file built for unknown-unsupported file format` , maybe I compiled the library incorrectly since the next message says it can't resolve the symbol in my called in the  cpp's main.

Any resources to learn how to do this properly?

Comment: _link with file built for unknown-unsupported file format_ that sounds a bit ominous.  What does `file` report for that file?  You can also try `lipo -info`.

Comment: it looks correct _libfoo.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64_

from lipo we get _Non-fat file: /Users/.../libfoo.dylib is architecture: x86_64_

Comment: OK, can you post the pertinent error message(s) in full please? (Add them to your question).

Comment: ok, done. I redefined the problem a bit.

Comment: OK, well, I've reached the limit of what I know.  I've not seen that message before, but the hex string in your post equates to `{    // See htt` so maybe there's a clue there.  It looks like you're trying to link a `json` file as a library, somehow, but I don't use VS code so that's all I know, sorry.,

Comment: yes I think you're right about it passing the json file. I was able to compile everything and get it to work in terminal so I think it's just a matter of not understanding how the predefined _$[]_ paths work in vscode. Nice translating the hex strings btw!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the argument formatting which resolved the issue. Also added `dependsOn` which creates the library first, then builds the dependent object and finally runs the executable in the sandbox folder.

```
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        { // creates dynamiclib
            "label": "build_lib",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args":
             [ "-dynamiclib",
                "-fPIC",// osx doesn't seem to need this but ok
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder:Engine}/bin/libfoo.dylib",
                "${workspaceFolder:Engine}/src/test.cpp",
            ],
            "group": "build"
        },

        { 
            "label": "build_engine",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [ 
                "--verbose",
                "${workspaceFolder:Sandbox}/src/libtesting.cpp",
                "-I", // include headers path for compiler
                 "${workspaceFolder:Engine}/src",
                "-L", // Library directory 
                "${workspaceFolder:Engine}/bin",
                "-l", // point to created libfoo library foo
                "foo",
                 "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder:Sandbox}/bin/testingout",      
                 ],
            "group":"build",
            "dependsOn":["build_lib"]
        },

        {
            "label": "run_sandbox",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "${workspaceFolder:Sandbox}/bin/testingout",
            "group": "build",
            "dependsOn":["build_engine"]
        }
    ]
}
```